# default selection with ajax request jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, default

Hi
I've made a ajax request selection tool in the right column.

http://www.lensfinder.se/testar5.php

How do I make a selection the default one? Because when you enter the page I want one to be open, now it hasen't made any request u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some simple javascript....

```
<script language="javascript"><!--
     document.getElementById('lins').value='Endagslins';
//--></script>
```

If you put this code somewhere **after** the select box, it should change the select box's value and trigger the getlenslist() function once the page is loaded. If you have any problems, you might need to attach this to the page's **onload** event.

alternatively, you can flag the select item you want selected like this:

```
<option value="Endagslins" selected>Endagslins</select>
```

This way, when the page loads, you will already have selected the correct item and you should only need to do

```
onload="getlenslist();"
```

Comment: I tried it out on the same page, with this line onload="document.getElementById('lins').value='Endagslins';"

It changes the default selecetion to "Endagslins" but it doesnt get the data?

Comment: onload="document.getElementById('lins').value='Endagslins';getlenslist();" also - See Updated Answer

Comment: I made it like this in the end because I have a wordpress site and doesnt want the onload thing on every page I put the onload to a image instead.

Comment: After the selectbox <img src="/img/blank.gif" onload="getlenslist();">

Comment: Good solution! The page/effect looks great. The only critique I have is you should start the ajax destination with no content at all. There seems to be some flashing text before the call to getlenslist() is made.